# Flask static css file

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm working on how to add value from flask into static/css file 
Here's my code from static/style.css:

```
.color1 {
    background-color: {{pickcolor}};
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.color2 {
    background-color: {{pickcolor}};
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

so the problem i got is underline error  **`property value expectedcss(css-propertyvalueexpected)`**

BUT when I use internal css in html file

```
<style>

    .color1 {
        background-color: {{pickcolor}};
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }

    .color2 {
        background-color: {{pickcolor}};
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }


</style>
```

There is no underline  problem with my {{pickcolor}}

Answer (score 0):

Your `style.css` file is probably not [templated](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/). I do not know about your exact project config but `static` files are usually not templated in general.

If you want to template your CSS file, first move it to the templates folder (usually `templates`), you will then have to create a view for it and use the URL of that view instead of a link to a static file. *e.g.*

```py
from flask import make_response, render_template

@app.route('/style.css')
def style():
    pickcolor = ...  # whatever

    # we explicitly create the response because we need to edit its headers
    response = make_response(render_template('style.css', pickcolor=pickcolor))

    # required to make the browser know it is CSS
    response['Content-type'] = 'text/css'

    return response
```

Then, in your HTML template

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('style') }}">
  </head>
  <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

Comment: my files is 

flask - app.py
        - templates/ index.html
        - static/ style.css

Comment: In my example you'd have to move `style.css` to folder `templates`, it will contain both `index.html` _and_ `style.css`.

Comment: my static file is in the same with templates. It's different folder